# Differentiating $f(x, y, c) = 0$ implicitly with respect to $x$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

My textbook claims that differentiating $f(x, y,  c) = 0$ implicitly with respect to $x$ gives us $g(x, y,  \dfrac{dy}{dx}, c) = 0$. It seems to me like we should be differentiating each term in $f$ with respect to $x$? How did the author arrive at this answer?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FULLY EDITED**

I'm assuming that $y=y(x)$, that $c$ is a constant and that $x$ is an the independant variable. The argument I will be using requires the use of the total derivative (similar to **@Thomas**) to account for the fact that $f$ depends on both $x$ and $y$ and that $y=y(x)$. I am not aware at this point if there is another way to prove this, although **@Fimpellizieri**'s example is a good intuition.

Using the total derivative formula,  $$\frac{d}{dx}f(x,y,c)= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dx}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial c}\frac{dc}{dx}$$

Of course, $\frac{dx}{dx}=1$ and $\frac{dc}{dx}=0$, since $c$ is assumed constant. This leaves us with $$\frac{d}{dx}f(x,y,c)= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}$$

Notice that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ are both partial derivatives. In the case of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, for example, this means that you take the derivative of $f$ with respect to $y$, temporarily assuming that $x$ and $c$ are constants. Same goes for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$; you are assuming that both $y$ and $c$ are constants.

From this last argument, we get that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ only depend on $x, y$ and $c$, but then there's still a $\frac{dy}{dx}$ term remaining. Therefore, $\frac{d}{dx}f(x,y,c)$ depends on $x, y, c$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: Thanks for the edited response. Your edit was useful and I understand your post. I will also make a note to self: The $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ in $\frac{d}{dx}f(x,y,c)= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}$ is because of the fact that $y = y(x)$ ($y$ is a dependent variable on $x$).

Comment: Good to know it helped! Indeed, the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ term remains because $y$ is dependant, but it can also be seen as a consequence of the chain rule : the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ term is sometimes called the "derivative of the inside function".

Answer (score 0):

It depends. You can take the derivative wrt to the first variable (which has been named $x$, which is a bit unfortunate in this setup) or you can take the derivative wrt to $x$ when $y$ or $y$ and $c$ may depend on $x$. In the latter case the chain rule applies
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x, y, c) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y,c) + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f (x,y,c)\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial}{\partial c} f(x,y,c) \frac{\partial c}{\partial x}$$
where, again a bit unfortunate, $x$ has two meanings and where we used $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}=1$

Answer (score 0):

The idea of *implicit* differentiation is that one assumes the equation $f(x,y)=c$ implicitly defines $y$ as a function of $x$.

> **Example:** Consider the equation $x^2+y^2=1$. If we assume this equation implicitly defines $y=y(x)$ as a function of $x$, then differentiating both sides with respect to $x$ yields
>
> $$2x+2y(x)\cdot y'(x)=0\iff x+yy'=0$$
>
> See how the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ comes up?

Now, in your example, I suppose $c$ is a constant? That is, it is not assumed to depend (implicitly) on $x$? This would explain why $\frac{dc}{dx}$ does not show up on $g$.